# How to create a stylesheet in Mapnik

Tags: gis, mapnik

This question is for Mapnik experts (node-mapnik experts are more welcome), GIS experts or XML experts. About stylesheet.xml file, I don't know how to make my own stylesheet. Is there an automated generation for a stylesheet for a specific place or city? I can't find any tutorials how to make a stylesheet. Can anyone tell me how to create your own stylesheet? I'm a complete beginner in Mapnik and GIS in general. Thanks! I'm using node-mapnik and trying to learn how to create an image for a specific place like let's say New York City.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A somewhat loosely structured answer to a loosely structured question...

[TileMill](https://www.mapbox.com/tilemill/) is a good place to start if you already have a geo-spatial dataset (shapefile, geojson, etc).

With TillMill you can load your dataset, view the map, create/edit the stylesheet to style that map, and then export that stylesheet to use for your own application.

Comment: Looks a like a very good place to start! Thanks for that somewhat loosely structured answer!